# When loading, the page goes on the bottom of it

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have an issue with my [website](http://www.ondinevermenot.fr). My page loads normally in Firefox, but when I use either Chrome or Safari, it goes to the bottom of the page and I don't understand why. I tried putting the following snippet at the beginning of the page, but no luck.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
});

</script>
```

Why does the page go to the bottom on loading?

Comment: Is there something in your page that gets the focus when the page is loaded? Perhaps this element is near the bottom of the page?

Comment: It works fine for me with chrome version 26.0.1410.43 m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When going to your site, I get redirected to http://www.ondinevermenot.fr/#start. That means the page will try to jump to the `start` element.

However, the `start` element is absolutely positioned. Therefore, when the page tries to jump down, the `start` element moves down with it. Therefore the page tries to jump down again. Then the `start` element moves down more. They keep going down until the bottom of the page, when there is no more room.

To fix it, don't redirect to `#start` when your page loads.

Because of the strangeness of jumping to something that's absolutely positioned, it's probably handled differently in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to have your image and other contents put inside div and set the box attribute of the div to margin:auto. works well with HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

i have an alturnative work around for you and incase you ever need to get to the top of the page - you can use this javascript as an alturnative:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webapplication).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight 0)");
```

however the other option would be to set a start up property: for example document.start("body.height = 0") something along those lines may work.

preferably id use option one as a code to start the broswer at a set height may not work so well for every browser. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 links to my home page in my footer. When I removed the links from my footer the problem went away.